# How do I set constant configuration parameters at run-time

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables

I am trying to achieve the following. I want to store some of the system information in a set of variables.

Say the variables are:

```
std::string GPU;
std::string CPU;
std::string OS;
```

I want these variables to have global scope, but only for reading (they should not be modified). Normally for this one would simply append `const` to the declaration. However for some of these variables I need to find the information at runtime after main has executed.

The issues is thus that I cannot simply initialize them statically as one normally would, I need to wait until some processing has been made to set them.

Overall I need the variables to be initialized once and exactly once by a function and then just be readable.

Is this achievable at all?

Comment: Sounds like you need the much-maligned singleton! Except you probably don't - why do you think these variables need to have global scope?

Comment: There is a namespace with multiple classes and methods. I want all of them to have access to this information since it's part of the system but I do not want to constantly pass them around.

Comment: Do they all need access to this information? Who's responsible for initialising them?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass them around? Passing things to functions is one of the basics of software engineering. It's highly unlikely that all your functions need access to these variables.

Comment: All classes and most non-class methods need access to them.

They get initialized by a single method that needs to be called to initialize the library before any method or class in the library can be used (there is a check for whether this function has been called)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Passing them around is would first require them to be stored somewhere (at this point equivalent to a global class) and constantly pass them from one method to the other, which is both tedious and occludes readability since it increases the number of parameters per function for no good reasons, since these values are just used to check for compatibility and selection of appropriate handling methods

Comment: Sorry, this is simply very, very poor programming practice - don't do it.

Comment: I am following the first comments advice in teh link at the bottom. Also, if this is not recommended, then what would be the way to achieve something similar?

It really makes no sense to force all functions to take three additional parameters that are the same for all classes and methods in the namespace
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47923/when-is-it-ok-to-use-a-global-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: So your question should really have been something like "How do I set constant configuration parameters at run-time"?

Comment: Well, perhaps. My initial question stands as is, that was what I wanted to know. But based on feedback it seems I should change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not hide required constants behind private static scope of a struct? In multithreaded environment you may even add a conditional variable and wait for initialization.

```
struct globals {
    static const std::string& GPU() {assert(is_inited_); return gpu_;}
    static init(std::string GPU, ...) {gpu_ = std::move(GPU); ...; is_inited_ = true;}
  private:
    std::string gpu_;
    std::string cpu_;
    std::string os_;
    book is_inited_;
};

int main() {
  ...
  // initialize consts at some point
  globals::init();
  ...
  // access consts
  globals::GPU();
}

// initial values
std::string globals::gpu_;
...
bool globals::is_inited_ = false;
```